# Calculating and storing lots of driving distances each day (PHP JavaScript)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, driving-directions, driving-distance

first time here so I'll try to be precise and detailed.

I'm working on a project where users will be able to sort local attractions by driving distance. The starting point will be their home address, the ending point will be one of the (many) attractions stored on the database: a lake, a park, a shop, a museum and so on.

A registered user needs to specify his/her address and the site will run a server-side script that will slowly find the distances between that address and the stored attractions.

The driving distance calculation is automatically triggered when:

1) a **new user registers** to the website

or

2) a **new attraction** is added to the database

Let's say I have 400 attractions and 1500 users. If I add a new attraction, the website will fetch the distance 1500 times (*one per user*). And if I add a new user, the website will do the same job for 400 times (*one per attraction*).

I am currently working with Goolge API's and they're pretty good. The only problem is... I've got a maximum of 2500 queries per day. So if I add 2 new attractions (*that will require a total of 3000 distances*) I am locked out until the next day.

In a bigger scenario, the driving distances can be quite long to retrieve. If I have 5000 registered users, whenever I add a new attraction I must fetch 5000 distances. That would take 2 days.

What could be a better approach? I was evaluating the Google Business API too (10.000$/year) but that would work for huge realities only, with good cash ad their disposal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to do it from the server side? Directions requests count against the IP address (2500 queries per day per IP), so you could do just a handful of requests in the background every time a visitor comes to the site and they would count against the visitor's IP, not the server's. You just need to be good with AJAX. ;-)

Comment: The request would come from the server anyway, so after I hit the free 2500-per-day I'm out :|

Comment: @ Skidrow @Loque, you did not read my answer. The 2500 hits per day are **per IP**. You can just do a handful at a time.

Comment: Hi Skid, sory for the delayed answer. Yes, it's 2500 per IP so the only way to process stuff without incurring in the limit is **working client-side**. But if I choose the server-side way, I'm screwed.

Comment: @Loque, I am not Skid.... and my suggestion is indeed to do it from the client side, one bit at a time, in the background of each visitor  ;-)

Comment: Ok, it looks like the client-side stuff is the only way. Thx everyone :)

Comment: @Loque: But with the 2500 limit you cannot do 5000 queries like you asked in your question?

Comment: @Skid sadly I can't, so I have to re-think some stuff OR use more than one machine to process data.

Answer (score 0):

Use the straight line instead. Don't use driving distances. Or store them in the database and use a spatial index.

Comment: Unfortunately a straight line from A to B wouldn't work at all in this scenario, because it would completely skip obstacles (_rivers, sea, mountains, etc_)... killing the purpose of displaying accurate driving distances.

Comment: Well, you can store them in the database but honestly with so many driving  distances you should pay a bit. Also you should think about how to make a difference between showing a route on a screen and travel that route in real life?

Comment: Yes, I store every fetched distance to avoid hammering Google on every access. So I basically use the API to get the A->B distance when I add a new record, then it gets saved on the database. The problem here is how to optimize things when I've got lots of users (_or attractions_) that would require multiple API calls (_greatly over 2500/day_).

Comment: You can use a spatial index to speed up things. A spatial index reduces the dimension and preserve spatial information.

Comment: But I still need to fetch the individual distances from Google (_using their API_) or any equivalent resource (_Bing, for example_). What worries me is being forced to query Google 5000 times if I have a new attraction that needs to be matched with the users (supposing I have 5000 registered members). I would like to get ALL the distances, but maybe I should skip those who are too far (say I want to show attractions within 0km and 50km, for example). Finding stuff inside a radius would be easy and fast (_SQL query_).

Comment: Yes, but what is your question?

Comment: If there is a better alternative than using Google API's (2500 free queries a day) or if I should skip this idea (fetching detailed distances) because it would be too intensive to process.

Comment: Yes, skip that idea and use a straight line!